# Get microsoft server 2008 sql query working on phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have the following query working on sql server managemengt  studio but it does not seem to work on phpmyadmin, Can anyone figure out what is wrong, It gives this error message "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 google_rank FROM eig_ranking mi WHERE mi.project_id = m.project_' at line 7"

I am using MySQL Version : 5.5.20 and php Version 5.3.13 and microsoft server 2008

```
 SELECT project_id,

   google_rank,

       COALESCE(
       (
       SELECT TOP 1 google_rank
       FROM eig_ranking mi
       WHERE mi.project_id = m.project_id
       ORDER BY
             project_id
       ), 0 - google_rank AS movement

       ,keyword
       ,domain

FROM  eig_ranking m where DATEDIFF(WEEK,rank_date, GETDATE())= 1 and google_rank!=0

order by movement desc
```

Comment: What's the `DATEDIFF` here? that's not even supported in mySql !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It your database is MySQL, then you need to write MySQL syntax and not Microsoft SQL Server syntax - replace `TOP` with `LIMIT`, and `DATEDIFF` arguments with the MySQL format, `GETDATE()` with `NOW()`, etc.

Comment: I have previously tried this, I know about the Mysql now() function. I replaced top with limit but I get a syntax error near 'LIMIT 1 google_rank FROM eig_ranking mi WHERE mi.project_id = m.pr' at line 7

Comment: LIMIT goes at the end in MySQL. ie: `ORDER BY project_id LIMIT 1`

Comment: thank you, I had also forgotten to add a closing bracket after 0

Answer (score 1):

There is no `SELECT TOP n` expression on MySQL.

In general on SQL Server syntax is a little bit different than on MySQL. You have to adjust SQL syntax details to MySQL (e.g. this `TOP`).